# How can I plot a function in R with complex numbers?

Tags: r, plot, complex-numbers

I want to plot the following function in R

```
f(w) = 1/(1-5*e^(-iw))
```

where i is the square root of -1.  Can R handle complex numbers in plotting?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should get you started (mostly by demonstrating the notation R uses for representing complex numbers and the exponential function).

```
f <- function(x) 1/(1-5*exp(-(0+1i)*x))
x <- seq(0, 2*pi, by=0.1)
plot(f(x), asp = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome thanks!  I'll accept the answer in 9 minutes when it lets me

Comment: Interestingly, `curve(f)` seems to behave differently, even though `plot.function` calls `curve`.

Comment: @joran -- That is interesting. The different result arises because `plot(f(x))` actually runs through `plot.default()` and from there `xy.coords()`, which has a branch that splits out the real and imaginary components of a complex number into `x` and `y` coordinates. The original `x` is only represented implicitly in the final plot, as an index of the curve of points.  `curve()`, on the other hand, plots the original `x` on on the abcissa and the real component of the returned complex number on the ordinate. (The imaginary component is simply thrown away).